# Word file parser

Tags: c#, parsing, pattern-matching, office-interop, string-matching

I am making a student level project in Visual Programming which includes reading a Word file and extracting personal info `Name,Age,GPA and other attributes of course (but I will discuss few just for the sake of simplicity)` from that.

The problem I encounter is how I find out where `Name` lies in Word file and what comes after name that could be `GPA or AGE`.


e.g

> Name: Juliet 
>  Age: 23

Of course after finding out its `Age` after name I would easily find out actual name. As it would lie in between `Name` and `Age`.

My thoughts till yet about achieving that is using Enum which will have all these attributes like `Name, Age, Gpa`.

```
Enum{
  Name, Age, Enum
}
```

Please suggest me if you have some ideas doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for a class I can give you only general guidance; I hope you find it helpful.

First off, there are several problems with using an Enum to represent your data. Typically you will want to use a Enum over a uniform data type to represent a set of related data. For example, the canonical example is something like:

```
enum DayOfWeek { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }
```

In this example, the underlying data type is the same. That is, we will use all integers (for example) to represent the underlying information. The whole point of this is so you can use descriptive types in your application rather than underlying primitive types. For example, you can say:

```
if (today == DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

and so on.

What you want to do is create a new object that can model your data, then populate that. In your example, I'd start with something like:

```
class Person
{
    private string name;
    private int    age;
    private double  gpa;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
        }
    }

    public double Gpa
    {
        get
        {
            return gpa;
        }
        set
        {
            gpa = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Your general plan will to be to iterate over your data source and gradually build up the objects. For example:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

// replace conditions with the conditions for your loop.
// this just loops forever.
for (; ; )
{
    Person p = new Person();

    // replace this with code that fetches out the actual values.
    p.Age = 20;
    p.Gpa = 4.0;
    p.Name = "John Doe";

    people.Add(p);

 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for writing alot but I have no use of classes as I will be just throwing them into DB. First of all I am concerned here with order of their appearance that either AGE come first or Name? and then I am concerned what comes after the first one. Thanks again

Comment: Moreover AGE,Name and GPA all are string so Enum stays valid here.

Comment: Enums represent single values. You want to represent a group of values. That is why Enum doesn't make sense here. Also, you can represent GPA and Age with strings, but you should get into the habit of using the correct data types for things.

Comment: To clarify: using Enum here offers nothing. If you don't intend to model your data you can just using plain strings.